# URL rename using re-write.properties in JBOSS

Tags: jboss

I am new in JBOSS. I would like to change my URL name using JBOSS's rewrite.properties to show just on screen URL.I would like to know, Is there any condition or regular expression or flags that can change the URL name instead of invoking or substituation to the URL.
For example, if the actual URL is "www.myexample.com/test" then it should be "www.myexample.com/yourtest"  while the operation is same expect the URL name differences.
Thanks.